# Как отсортировать по разнице значений трёх полей?

Tags: php, doctrine2

Начал изучать Doctrine 2 и переводить sql запросы на запросы к EntityManager `$this->em->getRepository(...)->...`
Но не могу перевести один запрос:
`SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY (a - b - c) DESC  LIMIT :offset, :rows`
a, b, c - поля в таблице mytable.
Везде приводится только пример как сортировать по разнице двух чисел, а вот как по разнеце трёх я не могу понять.
Как этот запрос переделать на запрос к EntityManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В DQL вы работаете не с таблицами БД, а с сущностями, поэтому вместо mytable в запросе должно быть название класса сущности (возможно, в сокращенной форме), а также его алиас. Этот алиас нужно использовать в качестве префикса для используемых атрибутов сущности:

```
SELECT entityAlias 
FROM NameSpace\EntityClassName entityAlias 
ORDER BY entityAlias.a - entityAlias.b - entityAlias.c
```

Выражение LIMIT непосредственно в DQL не поддерживается (возможно потому, что эта конструкция не является стандартной для SQL и по-разному реализована в разных диалектах). Однако, для установки смещения и количества результатов выборки можно воспользоваться методами [setFirstResult() и setMaxResults()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only).

По поводу последней части вопроса:

> Везде приводится только пример как сортировать по разнице двух чисел, а вот как по разнеце трёх я не могу понять.

Совершенно неважно сколько полей участвуют в выражении, 2, 3 или 100.

Comment: Про dql я понимаю, там все почти так же как и в sql разве что сущности вместо таблиц.но у меня все запросы в таком виде составлены `$this->em->getRepository(...)->...` и не хотелось бы отходить от стиля. Можно данный dql запрос сделать как-то так `$this->em->getRepository(...)->findBy(...)...` ?

Comment: Или предпочтмтельнее делать запросы на dql?

Comment: C findBy() ещё проще:

Comment: findBy() принимает четыре параметра: критерии выборки, параметры сортировки, смещение и лимит элементов: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#_findBy

Comment: Да, читал. Но вот не понял как мне масив сортировки сформировать, если просто по полю сортировать то ['id' => 'ASC'],  а вот каким должен быть массив чтоб по разнице трёх полей?

Comment: Тогда только через DQL.